# perl from url or file patch get the name of image and extension

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get the name and extension of image for either a URL or local path specified with either forward or backward slashes

Input could be
http://test.com/hi23.gif 
or
/local/test/hi23.gif
or
C:\test\323.gif
or 
file:\bla\3235.gif

```
#input: filename (i.e: http://test.com/hi4324.gif)
sub getFileName
{
  my $input = shift;  
  (my $filename = $input)  =~ m/(\w+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$)/i;  
  return $filename;
}

#input: filename (i.e: hi4324.gif)
sub getExtension
{
  my $input = shift;  
  (my $extension = $input)  =~ m/\w+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$/i;  
  return $extension;
}
```

Comment: Algorithm tip: just look for the chunk of text between the *last* frontslash or backslash, and before the very last `.`

Comment: Is this a better way? my ($name, undef, $ext) = fileparse($in_str, "jpg", "png", "gif");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your input is always going to end with `/filename.ext`, then use a simple regex:

```
# $url has your url already
$url =~ /.*\/(.*?)\.(.*)/;
my ($filename, $ext) = ($1,$2);
```

But if it can be more complicated with query strings or other various formats, then it's much easier to start pulling in modules. There just gets to be too many variables. I've always found [File::Basename](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aBasename) to be the best to use for this when working with a file system. I don't think that will work for URLs, though. The main [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) module looks like it might suffice. [URI::Split](http://p3rl.org/URI%3a%3aSplit) and [APR::URI](http://p3rl.org/APR%3a%3aURI) may offer a bit more flexibility.

Comment: Assigning `$1,$2` without conditional is not good practice, as it may introduce hard to detect bugs. Use `my ($filename, $ext) = $url =~ m#/(.*?)\.(.*)$#` (yeah, fixed the regex too). Or use `if ($url =~ ...) { #assignment }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
my @input = qw( http://test.com/hi23.gif  /local/test/hi23.gif  C:\test\323.gif file:\bla\3235.gif);

foreach my $some(@input){ 
$some =~ s!\\!/!g;          
my $basename = basename( $some);

if($basename =~ m/(.*)\.(.*)/){
my ($image_name,$image_extension) = ($1,$2);
print "\nInput is $some\nImage name is = $image_name, and extension is   $image_extension";
};
}

OUTPUT

Input is http://test.com/hi23.gif
Image name is = hi23, and extension is gif
Input is /local/test/hi23.gif
Image name is = hi23, and extension is gif
Input is C:/test/323.gif
Image name is = 323, and extension is gif
Input is file:/bla/3235.gif
Image name is = 3235, and extension is gif
```

Comment: You can use `tr///` instead of `s!\\!/!g` : `$some =~ tr#\\#/#`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a subroutine that returns both the whole filename and the extension?

```
sub getFileNameExt {
  my ($path) = @_;
  return $1, $2 if $path =~ m{([^\\/.]+([^\\/]*)$)};
}

for my $p (qw(
    http://test.com/hi23.gif
    /local/test/hi23.gif
    C:\test\323.gif
    file:\bla\3235.gif)) {

  printf "%s - %s\n", getFileNameExt($p);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hi23.gif - .gif
hi23.gif - .gif
323.gif - .gif
3235.gif - .gif
```